# Mysql sum of grouped data

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

I have the following tables:

**products** (id, name, price, category)

**sales** (product_id, timestamp)

I have to following summary of all my sales:

```
SELECT products.name AS products, TRUNCATE(products.price/100,2) as price, 
   COUNT(*) as sales_nbr, TRUNCATE(products.price/100*COUNT(*),2) as total
   FROM sales
   LEFT JOIN products ON sales.product_id=products.id
   GROUP BY product_id
   ORDER BY products.category

+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
| Products          | price | sales_nbr | total  |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
| Hot-dog           |  4.00 |    99     | 396.00 |
| Sandwich          |  4.00 |    64     | 256.00 |
| Croissant/brioche |  2.00 |    31     |  62.00 |
| Frites            |  5.00 |   106     | 530.00 |
...
```

I want the **last row** to be something like:

```
| TOTAL OF ALL SALES|       |   300     |1244.00 |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

I tried with *SUM()* and *UNION*, but nothing seems to be working :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ROLLUP which is explain here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT products.name AS products, TRUNCATE(products.price/100,2) as price, 
   COUNT(*) as sales_nbr, TRUNCATE(products.price/100*COUNT(*),2) as total
   FROM sales
   LEFT JOIN products ON sales.product_id=products.id
   GROUP BY product_id WITH ROLLUP
   ORDER BY products.category
```

Or, if you want just the two last columns to be summed you can do it with union

```
SELECT products.name AS products, TRUNCATE(products.price/100,2) as price, 
   COUNT(*) as sales_nbr, TRUNCATE(products.price/100*COUNT(*),2) as total
   FROM sales
   LEFT JOIN products ON sales.product_id=products.id
   GROUP BY product_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL OF ALL SALES' , null, 
   COUNT(*) as sales_nbr, SUM(TRUNCATE(products.price/100,2)) as total
   FROM sales
   LEFT JOIN products ON sales.product_id=products.id
ORDER BY products.category
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution worked fine :-) (except the *ORDER BY products.category* but it's doesn't matter)